# How to use the DICT protocol client in Python?

Tags: python, dict-protocol

I use the command line [DICT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICT) client named `dict` like this : `dict <some word>`, which will show me the meaning from the dictionary servers which I have configured.

I'd like to interact with the dict servers from Python, for example reimplement that command line client in Python.

I found a Python module for the dict protocol in the Ubuntu repositories that I've installed (`apt-get install python-dictclient`), but unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation for this module. I tried to understand the modules's builtin help `help('dictclient')` but didn't succeed. I could only make a connection to a dict server and was able to see apartial definition, here's my attempt :

```
import dictclient
c = dictclient.Connection('localhost', 2628)
```

If anyone has experience with this module please explain to me how to use it.

Comment: could someone who have more than 1500 reputation create new tag dict for dict protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict-like definition fetching using dictclient in Python:

```
from dictclient import Connection, Database
from sys import argv

con = Connection("dict.org") #or whatever your server is
db = Database(con, "*") #replace * with ! to get only the first result
def_list = db.define(argv[1]) #list containing Definition objects
for x in def_list:
    print x.getdefstr() + '\n'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is [a Python3 version of dictlient](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krisvandermerwe/dictclient/db077f0d806e0afa866106a0ec0ce7682ed1931c/dictclient.py):

> ```
> # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
> # Client for the DICT protocol (RFC2229)
> #
> # Copyright (C) 2002 John Goerzen
> #
> #    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
> #    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
> #    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
> #    (at your option) any later version.
> #
> #    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
> #    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
> #    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
> #    GNU General Public License for more details.
> #
> #    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
> #    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
> #    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
> #    A few small hacks to make it work on Python3  - KrisvanderMerwe 25 Aoril 2015
>
> import socket, re
>
> version = '1.0.2.1'
>
> def dequote(teks):
>     """Will remove single or double quotes from the start and end of a string
>     and return the result."""
>     quotechars = "'\""
>     while len(teks) and teks[0] in quotechars:
>         teks = teks[1:]
>     while len(teks) and teks[-1] in quotechars:
>         teks = teks[0:-1]
>     return teks
>
> def enquote(teks):
>     """This function will put a string in double quotes, properly
>     escaping any existing double quotes with a backslash.  It will
>     return the result."""
>     return '"' + teks.replace('"', "\\\"") + '"'
>
> class Connection:
>     """This class is used to establish a connection to a database server.
>     You will usually use this as the first call into the dictclient library.
>     Instantiating it takes two optional arguments: a hostname (a string)
>     and a port (an int).  The hostname defaults to localhost
>     and the port to 2628, the port specified in RFC."""
>     def __init__(self, hostname = 'localhost', port = 2628):
>         self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>         self.sock.connect((hostname, port))
>
>         self.rfile = self.sock.makefile()
>         self.wfile = self.sock.makefile("wb", 0)
>
>         self.saveconnectioninfo()
>
>     def getresultcode(self):
>         """Generic function to get a result code.  It will return a list
>         consisting of two items: the integer result code and the text
>         following.  You will not usually use this function directly."""
>         line = self.rfile.readline().strip()
>         code, text = line.split(' ', 1)
>         return [int(code), text]
>
>     def get200result(self):
>         """Used when expecting a single line of text -- a 200-class
>         result.  Returns [intcode, remaindertext]"""
>
>         code, text = self.getresultcode()
>         if code < 200 or code >= 300:
>             raise Exception ("Got '%s' when 200-class response expected %s " % (code,text) )
>
>         return [code, text]
>
>     def get100block(self):
>         """Used when expecting multiple lines of text -- gets the block
>         part only.  Does not get any codes or anything!  Returns a string."""
>         data = []
>         while 1:
>             line = self.rfile.readline().strip()
>             if line == '.':
>                 break
>             data.append(line)
>         return "\n".join(data)
>
>     def get100result(self):
>         """Used when expecting multiple lines of text, terminated by a period
>         and a 200 code.  Returns: [initialcode, [bodytext_1lineperentry],
>         finalcode]"""
>         code, text = self.getresultcode()
>         if code < 100 or code >= 200:
>             raise Exception ("Got '%s' when 100-class response expected" %  code )
>
>         bodylines = self.get100block().split("\n")
>
>         code2 = self.get200result()[0]
>         return [code, bodylines, code2]
>
>     def get100dict(self):
>         """Used when expecting a dictionary of results.  Will read from
>         the initial 100 code, to a period and the 200 code."""
>         dicl = {}
>         for line in self.get100result()[1]:
>             key, val = line.split(' ', 1)
>             dicl[key] = dequote(val)
>         return dicl
>
>     def saveconnectioninfo(self):
>         """Called by __init__ to handle the initial connection.  Will
>         save off the capabilities and messageid."""
>         code, string = self.get200result()
>         assert code == 220
>         capstr, msgid = re.search('<(.*)> (<.*>)$', string).groups()
>         self.capabilities = capstr.split('.')
>         self.messageid = msgid
>
>     def getcapabilities(self):
>         """Returns a list of the capabilities advertised by the server."""
>         return self.capabilities
>
>     def getmessageid(self):
>         """Returns the message id, including angle brackets."""
>         return self.messageid
>
>     def getdbdescs(self):
>         """Gets a dict of available databases.  The key is the db name
>         and the value is the db description.  This command may generate
>         network traffic!"""
>         if hasattr(self, 'dbdescs'):
>             return self.dbdescs
>
>         self.sendcommand("SHOW DB")
>         self.dbdescs = self.get100dict()
>         return self.dbdescs
>
>     def getstratdescs(self):
>         """Gets a dict of available strategies.  The key is the strat
>         name and the value is the strat description.  This call may
>         generate network traffic!"""
>         if hasattr(self, 'stratdescs'):
>             return self.stratdescs
>
>         self.sendcommand("SHOW STRAT")
>         self.stratdescs = self.get100dict()
>         return self.stratdescs
>
>     def getdbobj(self, dbname):
>         """Gets a Database object corresponding to the database name passed
>         in.  This function explicitly will *not* generate network traffic.
>         If you have not yet run getdbdescs(), it will fail."""
>         if not hasattr(self, 'dbobjs'):
>             self.dbobjs = {}
>
>         if dbname in self.dbobjs:
>             return self.dbobjs[dbname]
>
>         # We use self.dbdescs explicitly since we don't want to
>         # generate net traffic with this request!
>
>         if dbname != '*' and dbname != '!' and \
>                not dbname in self.dbdescs.keys():
>             raise Exception( "Invalid database name '%s'" % dbname )
>
>         self.dbobjs[dbname] = Database(self, dbname)
>         return self.dbobjs[dbname]
>
>     def sendcommand(self, command):
>         """Takes a command, without a newline character, and sends it to
>         the server."""
>         self.wfile.write(command.encode() + b"\n")
>
>     def define(self, database, word):
>         """Returns a list of Definition objects for each matching
>         definition.  Parameters are the database name and the word
>         to look up.  This is one of the main functions you will use
>         to interact with the server.  Returns a list of Definition
>         objects.  If there are no matches, an empty list is returned.
>
>         Note: database may be '*' which means to search all databases,
>         or '!' which means to return matches from the first database that
>         has a match."""
>         self.getdbdescs()               # Prime the cache
>
>         if database != '*' and database != '!' and \
>            not database in self.getdbdescs():
>             raise Exception ( "Invalid database '%s' specified" % database )
>
>         self.sendcommand("DEFINE " + enquote(database) + " " + enquote(word))
>         code = self.getresultcode()[0]
>
>         retval = []
>
>         if code == 552:
>             # No definitions.
>             return []
>         if code != 150:
>             raise Exception ("Unknown code %d" % code )
>
>         while 1:
>             code, text = self.getresultcode()
>             if code != 151:
>                 break
>
>             resultword, resultdb = re.search('^"(.+)" (\S+)', text).groups()
>             defstr = self.get100block()
>             retval.append(Definition(self, self.getdbobj(resultdb),
>                                      resultword, defstr))
>         return retval
>
>     def match(self, database, strategy, word):
>         """Gets matches for a query.  Arguments are database name,
>         the strategy (see available ones in getstratdescs()), and the
>         pattern/word to look for.  Returns a list of Definition objects.
>         If there is no match, an empty list is returned.
>
>         Note: database may be '*' which means to search all databases,
>         or '!' which means to return matches from the first database that
>         has a match."""
>         self.getstratdescs()            # Prime the cache
>         self.getdbdescs()               # Prime the cache
>         if not strategy in self.getstratdescs().keys():
>             raise Exception ( "Invalid strategy '%s'" % strategy )
>         if database != '*' and database != '!' and  not database in self.getdbdescs().keys():
>             raise Exception ( "Invalid database name '%s'" % database )
>
>         self.sendcommand("MATCH %s %s %s" % (enquote(database),
>                                              enquote(strategy),
>                                              enquote(word)))
>         code = self.getresultcode()[0]
>         if code == 552:
>             # No Matches
>             return []
>         if code != 152:
>             raise Exception ( "Unexpected code %d" % code )
>
>         retval = []
>
>         for matchline in self.get100block().split("\n"):
>             matchdict, matchword = matchline.split(" ", 1)
>             retval.append(Definition(self, self.getdbobj(matchdict),
>                                      dequote(matchword)))
>         if self.getresultcode()[0] != 250:
>             raise Exception ( "Unexpected end-of-list code %d" % code )
>         return retval
>
> class Database:
>     """An object corresponding to a particular database in a server."""
>     def __init__(self, dictconn, dbname):
>         """Initialize the object -- requires a Connection object and
>         a database name."""
>         self.conn = dictconn
>         self.name = dbname
>
>     def getname(self):
>         """Returns the short name for this database."""
>         return self.name
>
>     def getdescription(self):
>         if hasattr(self, 'description'):
>             return self.description
>         if self.getname() == '*':
>             self.description = 'All Databases'
>         elif self.getname() == '!':
>             self.description = 'First matching database'
>         else:
>             self.description = self.conn.getdbdescs()[self.getname()]
>         return self.description
>
>     def getinfo(self):
>         """Returns a string of info describing this database."""
>         if hasattr(self, 'info'):
>             return self.info
>
>         if self.getname() == '*':
>             self.info = "This special database will search all databases on the system."
>         elif self.getname() == '!':
>             self.info = "This special database will return matches from the first matching database."
>         else:
>             self.conn.sendcommand("SHOW INFO " + self.name)
>             self.info = "\n".join(self.conn.get100result()[1])
>         return self.info
>
>     def define(self, word):
>         """Get a definition from within this database.
>         The argument, word, is the word to look up.  The return value is the
>         same as from Connection.define()."""
>         return self.conn.define(self.getname(), word)
>
>     def match(self, strategy, word):
>         """Get a match from within this database.
>         The argument, word, is the word to look up.  The return value is
>         the same as from Connection.define()."""
>         return self.conn.match(self.getname(), strategy, word)
>
> class Definition:
>     """An object corresponding to a single definition."""
>     def __init__(self, dictconn, db, word, defstr = None):
>         """Instantiate the object.  Requires: a Connection object,
>         a Database object (NOT corresponding to '*' or '!' databases),
>         a word.  Optional: a definition string.  If not supplied,
>         it will be fetched if/when it is requested."""
>         self.conn = dictconn
>         self.db = db
>         self.word = word
>         self.defstr = defstr
>
>     def getdb(self):
>         """Get the Database object corresponding to this definition."""
>         return self.db
>
>     def getdefstr(self):
>         """Get the definition string (the actual content) of this
>         definition."""
>         if not self.defstr:
>             self.defstr = self.conn.define(self.getdb().getname(), self.word)[0].getdefstr()
>         return self.defstr
>
>     def getword(self):
>         """Get the word this object describes."""
>         return self.word
> ```